# Whats the correct way to embed images PHPMailer with an HTML email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to send an Newsletter with PHPMAiler. The newsletter does work, but I'm wondering if there is a better option to do this.

What I have is.

1. HTML Page
2. Images

Now my code looks as follows

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Adding the body
$body = file_get_contents('template/index.htm');

$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody = "To view this message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";


$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

$address = ".......@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "xxxxxxx");

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("template/images/bullet_point.gif","1");
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("template/images/template_1_01.gif","2");
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("template/images/template_1_03.gif","3");


$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I use file_get_contents to get the html page, and AddEmbeddedImage to embed images, now is there a way to pass only the HTML page to PHPMailer and that PHP Mailer will embed these images automatically?

Comment: You could just load images from outer source, if that fits your needs. Mails would be smaller to send and receive.

Comment: This won't work in my situation, since the images could be moved at any stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible *(automatically adding required images)* with PHPMailer "from scratch".

Maybe you could parse the HTML to get the list of images it links to ? There are at least 2 ways of doing that :

- using rexexes ; generally not the best way to do things if you're trying to extract data from HTML -- and you are ^^
- another (probably) better way would be using [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) on the HTML content loaded from your file (the output of `file_get_contents`), and work with the methods of [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (and, why not, [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) ?)

To get the images, I suppose you have `<img>` tags in your e-mail, with `src` attributes ; the goal is to find the values of those ones ;-)

Once you have the list of images path, you iterate over them, and call `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage` on each one of them.

I suppose that would work just fine *(haven't tried though, but I don't see why it wouldn't)*.

As a side note, the other way would be to keep the images on your server for a couple of days/weeks/months, and not include them in the mail ; it would make the mails smaller, which means :

- less bandwith spent on your side (if your are sending lots of mails, it can represent quite an amout of bandwith)
- less bandwith spent on each one of your clients' side -- which is nice for them too ^^
- less space used on their hard disks ;-)

And to make sure the images don't get erased / replaced on the server before a couple of weeks/month, you can create a new directory for each newsletter, containing it's images -- and once in a while, delete the directories older than `X` days.